# asp.net and matlab

Tags: asp.net, matlab

I have successfully developed an application in asp.net which calls a matlab function and produces the results as an integer...the problem is I need to pass this value back to asp.net to proceed with the further process as to which page to redirect.

Comment: I didn't know this was even possible. Can you show us some code or explain how you did it?

Comment: @brixy: can you be more specific, did you use the MATLAB Compiler (Builde NE Toolbox) to create a .NET assembly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using the NE Toolbox?

If so, in C# this is how you would do it.

Matlab Function cellexamp.m:

```
function out = OutInt
num = 10;
out = { num };
```

Run deploytool in Matlab

MATLAB Builder for .NET -> .NET Component
Project/Component name: MyOutIntProject
Class name: MyOutIntClass

C#:

```
using System;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MyOutIntProject;

namespace IntTest
{
    class CellExampleApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MWCellArray myIntCell = null;
            try
            {
                MyOutIntClass obj = new MyOutIntClass();
                myIntCell = (MWCellArray)obj.OutInt();

                MWNumericArray item = (MWNumericArray)cellexp[1];

                Console.WriteLine("item is {0}", item);

                double[,] native = (double[,])item.ToArray(MWArrayComponent.Real);            
                Console.ReadLine();
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Even though your num variable seems to be an int, Matlab moves everything back and forth through its MWNumericArray. Your native[0,0] variable will be '10' in this case.

This example shows [This shows how to use MWArray.dll for moving strings, arrays and ints](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-3NL1YX/index.html?solution=1-3NL1YX)